# Trying to add a UIButton to my view with Auto Layout, but it's not appearing. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following code:

```
- (void)addLogoutButton {
    UIButton *logoutButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    logoutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [logoutButton setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:logoutButton];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:logoutButton
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:-100.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:logoutButton
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:40.0]];


    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:logoutButton
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                 constant:-40]];
}
```

But when I run the app, the button is nowhere to be found. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first constraints constant to `+100.0` and init your button with:

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```